# Вычисление данных на основании двух массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Стоит задача реализовать метод:

```
public String getSalaryInfo(String[] names, String[] data, String dateFrom, String dateTo)
```

где

1. `String[] names` - массив фамилий сотрудников
2. `String[] data` - массив данных для вычисления заработной платы в формате:

```
    "26.04.2019 Иванов 4 50" 
    "26.04.2019 Петров 4 50"
    //   05.04.2019 Сидоров 3 200
    //   10.04.2019 Семенова 7 100
    //   22.04.2019 Семенова 9 100
    //   25.06.2019 Иванов 11 50
    //   26.04.2019 Петров 3 150
    //   13.02.2019 Сидоров 7 100
    //   26.04.2019 Сидоров 9 100
```

где числа 4 и 50 данные для вычисления зп (4часа*50уе-200уе в этот день он заработал)

3. `dateFrom`, `dateTo` соответственно данные за какой период посчитать зп сотрудников.

Нужно реализовать методы, чтобы отображалась информация в формате:

```
Отчет за период #дата_1# - #дата_2#
#Имя сотрудника# - #заработанные деньги#
****Report for period 01.04.2019  - 30.04.2019**  
Иванов - 200
Петров - 650
Сидоров - 1500**
```

Пока солянка получилась такая, но код не работает корректно (((

```
    public String getSalaryInfo(String[] names, String[] data, String dateFrom, String dateTo) {
            String month = dateFrom.substring(3, 5);
            String nameOfEmployee = "";
            int sumSalary = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
                    if (data[i].contains(names[j]) && month.equals(data[i].substring(3, 5))) {
                        nameOfEmployee = names[j];
                        String dataValue = data[i].substring(data[i].indexOf(" "));
                        int l = dataValue.length();
                        int sum = 0;
                        String temp = "";
                        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
                        {
                            if (Character.isDigit(dataValue.charAt(k)))
                            {
                                if (k < l-1 && Character.isDigit(dataValue.charAt(k+1)))
                                {
                                    temp += dataValue.charAt(k);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    temp += dataValue.charAt(k);
                                    sum += Integer.parseInt(temp);
                                    temp = "";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
    
            }
            String resultAnswer = "Report for period " + dateFrom + "-" + dateTo + nameOfEmployee + " "
                    + sumSalary;
    
            return resultAnswer;
        }
```

Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: Зачем вообще фамилии нужны,  если фамилия в данных есть?

Comment: Ну и вообще, я бы советовал строки распарсить сначала в какой то свой класс и оттуда собирать отчёт

Comment: Фамилии нужны так как в Массиве Дата могут быть все сотрудники допустим а нам нужно получить данные не по всем сотрудникам

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы **без явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Это не работает" - это не описание проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует создать классы для представления строки данных (похожий вопрос: [База данных на java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497057/)) и для агрегации данных для отчёта (вычисления суммарной зарплаты по произведению часов на ставку).  Также необходимо корректно реализовать парсинг даты в формате `dd.mm.yyyy` и метод для фильтрации даты в списке.

С использованием кортежей `record` в Java 16+ реализация класса достаточно тривиальна, однако потребуется написать конструктор/метод для парсинга строки:

```java
record DataRow(LocalDate date, String name, int hours, int rate) {}

public static final DateTimeFormatter DDMMYYYY = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

public static DataRow parse(String str) {
    String[] cols = str.split("\\s+"); // разбить на колонки
    return new DataRow(
        LocalDate.parse(cols[0], DDMMYYYY), // дата
        cols[1],                            // имя
        Integer.parseInt(cols[2]),          // часы
        Integer.parseInt(cols[3])           // почасовой тариф
    );
}
```

Метод для фильтра по дате может быть такой:

```java
public static boolean between(LocalDate d, LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    return d.isAfter(from) || d.isEqual(from) && d.isBefore(to);
}
```

Тогда реализация метода может выглядеть так (используя Stream API для краткости):

```java
public String getSalaryInfo(String[] names, String[] data, String dateFrom, String dateTo) {
    LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse(dateFrom, DDMMYYYY);
    LocalDate to = LocalDate.parse(dateTo, DDMMYYYY);

    Set<String> set = Set.of(names);

    Map<String, Integer> salaryMap = Arrays.stream(data)
        .map(row -> parse(row)) // Stream<DataRow>
        .filter(row -> set.contains(row.name()) && between(row.date(), from, to))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            DataRow::name,
            Collectors.summingInt(row -> row.hours() * row.rate())
        ));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("**** Report for period ")
      .append(dateFrom).append(" - ").append(dateTo).append(" ****\n");
    Arrays.stream(names)
        .forEach(name -> sb
            .append(name)
            .append(" - ")
            .append(salaryMap.containsKey(name) 
                ? String.valueOf(salaryMap.get(name)) 
                : "---"
            )
            .append("\n")
        );
    return sb.toString();  
}
```

Тест:

```java
String[] data = {
    "26.04.2019 Иванов 4 50", 
    "26.04.2019 Петров 4 50",
    "05.04.2019 Сидоров 3 200",
    "10.04.2019 Семенова 7 100",
    "22.04.2019 Семенова 9 100",
    "25.06.2019 Иванов 11 50",
    "26.04.2019 Петров 3 150",
    "13.02.2019 Сидоров 7 100",
    "26.04.2019 Сидоров 9 100"
};

String[] names = {"Иванов", "Петров", "Сидоров", "Михайлов"};

System.out.println(getSalaryInfo(names, data, "01.04.2019", "01.05.2019"));
```

Результат:

```
**** Report for period 01.04.2019 - 01.05.2019 ****
Иванов - 750
Петров - 650
Сидоров - 1500
Михайлов - ---
```

Comment: Спасибо @Nowhere Man Хотел уточнить а есть вариант проще реализовать данный вопрос?

Comment: Что значит "проще"?  Выделение бизнес-сущности в виде отдельного класса, использование современных стандартных/библиотечных средств языка (коллекции / record / Date/Time API, Stream API), которые специально были придуманы для повышения эффективности кода, как раз и упрощает решение.   А принудительное самоограничение более _простыми_ строками, циклами, массивами приведёт к разрастанию и _усложнению_ кода, так как большую часть стандартного функционала придётся реализовывать самому.

Comment: Принял огромное спасибо за вашу помощь. !!!